# OnListItemClick not working in listfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

i have a list fragment in my project and when u select an item from it. it is suppose to change the fragments but it doesn't seem like it is receiving the clicks at all. i have tried setting the descendents focusability but nothing seems to be getting it to even register myclicks. i have tried solutions i have seen on this site because it seems like a common issue but none of them seem to be allowing my particular program to work properly

Here is my ListFragment:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class CharacterListFragment extends ListFragment{



    ArrayList<String> charList = new ArrayList<String>();





    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.character_list, null, false);
         ListView ls = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         ls.setClickable(false);
         return view;
        }
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);
         String clickedDetail = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

         CharacterFragment myCharFragment = new CharacterFragment();
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("KEY_DETAIL", clickedDetail);
         myCharFragment.setArguments(bundle);
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.simpleFragment, myCharFragment);
         fragmentTransaction.commit(); 

     }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        db.open();
        charList = db.getArrayList();
        db.close();



        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, charList));
    }


}
```

And my Fragment Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false" >
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't know if its something simple that i am just overlooking

Comment: why do you have this `ls.setClickable(false);`?

Comment: i add that after a whole list of things that didn't help that included

Comment: i just removed it and like i said it still isn't doing anything from clicks

Comment: i don't see the need for a layout. Since it is a `ListFragment`. and remove `onCreateView` also. and log something `onListItemClick` it should work

Comment: oh wow that fixed it thank you so much the only problem now is that it is putting the other fragment on top of it instead of replacing the list all the way

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnArticleSelectedListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Append the clicked item's row ID with the content provider Uri
        Uri noteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, id);
        // Send the event and Uri to the host activity
        mListener.onArticleSelected(noteUri);
    }
    ...
```

This will work for OnListItemClick in listFragment